# Is my python code enough to retrieve ec2 instance status from other accounts?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**Problem**

I have a Lambda function in Account 1, which retrieves EC2 instance status.
Similarly, I want to retrieve EC2 instance status in other 4 accounts.

**What I did**

I Created trust relationship with the other 4 account by updating the IAM role.

**Question:**

Will my python code (residing in my lambda function in account 1) is enough to retrieve ec2 instance status from the other 4 accounts? or should I do something more ?

Please suggest!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each AWS Account is separate. You cannot access details of one AWS Account from another AWS Account. However, you can temporarily assume an IAM Role from another account to gain access.

Instead, you will need to:

- Create an IAM Role for the central Lambda function (`Lambda-Role`) and grant it permission to call `AssumeRole`
- Create an **IAM Role in each account** that you wish to access, grant it permission to call `DescribeInstances` and configure it to trust `Lambda-Role`
- The Lambda function can then loop through each account and:

  - Call `AssumeRole` for that account, which will return temporary credentials
  - Use those credentials to call `DescribeInstances`

Comment: Thanks for your reply John, Let me explore this and try to complete my task. Once done will accept your answer.